# Unable to use Template Tags

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to create a form with dependent dropdowns so far I have been able to add the required triggers but I just noticed that the response message wasn't rendering template tags 
Even other HTML files that I try to add template tags to just gets ignored 
I have no clue what is even causing this kind of error

After viewing a few other posts which said that if I were to use {% load XYZ %}. That I should use this load tag in all my HTML pages but this didn't solve my problem

my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from status.forms import StatusForm
from status.models import FlightStatus
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView, UpdateView
from postlog.models import Flight
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
# Create your views here.
class StatusPageView(CreateView):

    template_name = "status/home.html"
    model = FlightStatus
    form_class = StatusForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('status') 

def load_park_bay(request):
    flightid = request.GET.get('flight1')
    parks = Flight.objects.filter(fl_no='flightid').order_by('park_bay')
    context = {'parks': parks}
    return render(request, 'status/park_bay_dropdown_list.html', context)
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.StatusPageView.as_view(), name='status'),
    path('ajax/load-park/', views.load_park_bay, name='ajax_load_park'),
]
```

my home page where my form is present home.html:

```
{% extends 'base_template1.html' %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

{% block title %} Status {% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
<div class="modal fade" id="Add_Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Add_ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="AddModalLabel">Flight Details</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" id="statusForm" data-parks-url="{% url 'ajax_load_park' %}" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Details</button>
      </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  <script>
    $("#id_fl_no").change(function () {
      var url = $("#statusForm").attr("data-parks-url");
      var flightId = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
          'flight1': flightId
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $("#id_park_bay").html(data);
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
{%endblock%}
```

the html response served as response to the ajax request park_bay_dropdown.html:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<option value="">---------</option>
{% for park in parks %}
    <option value="{{ park.fl_no }}">{{ park.park_bay }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Response received:[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE1ja.jpg)
even when I tried to send the form instance as a context for displaying the complete form none of the template tags was even shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are storing the value of `'flight1'` coming from ajax in variable `flightid`. So you need to write flightid without ' ' in Query. And also keep practice to convert the `id` coming form Ajax into `int` to avoid any error while querying through ORM. So your view would be like this.

```
def load_park_bay(request):
    flightid = int(request.GET.get('flight1'))
    parks = Flight.objects.filter(fl_no=flightid).order_by('park_bay')
    context = {'parks': parks}
    return render(request, 'status/park_bay_dropdown_list.html', context)
```

Comment: This would work only if the fl_no which is a charfield had numeric values  like 1,2,3 etc but if the values were to be like EK565,Eb565 it would probably not work. Would it be better to query based on the I'd value

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works only if there is a numeric value.